# Iterator but still ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, concurrentmodification, concurrentskiplistmap

All,

Running into the issue of ConcurrentModificationException and struggling to find a resolution partly because I can't see where I am modifiying the list while iterating it... Any ideas?? I've highlighted the line that is causing the issue (it3.remove()). Really at a standstill with this one..

EDIT: Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.shimmerresearch.advancepc.InternalFrameAndPlotManager.subtractMaps(InternalFrameAndPlotManager.java:1621)
```

Line 1621 corresponds to it3.remove() in my referenced code above.

```
private void subtractMaps(ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, PlotDeviceDetails> firstMap, ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, PlotDeviceDetails> secondMap) {

    // iterate through the secondmap
    Iterator<Entry<String, PlotDeviceDetails>> it1 = secondMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, PlotDeviceDetails> itEntry = (Entry) it1.next();
        String mapKey = (String) it1Entry.getKey();
        PlotDeviceDetails plotDeviceDetails = (PlotDeviceDetails)it1Entry.getValue();

        // if we find an entry that exists in the second map and not in the first map continue
        if(!firstMap.containsKey(mapKey)){
            continue;
        }

         // iterate through a list of channels belonging to the secondmap
        Iterator <PlotChannelDetails> it2 = plotDeviceDetails.mListOfPlotChannelDetails.iterator(); 
        while (it2.hasNext()) {
            PlotChannelDetails it2Entry = it2.next();

            // iterate through a list of channels belonging to the firstmap
            Iterator <PlotChannelDetails> it3 = firstMap.get(mapKey).mListOfPlotChannelDetails.iterator();
            innerloop:
            while(it3.hasNext()){
                // if a channel is common to both first map and second map, remove it from firstmap
                PlotChannelDetails it3Entry = it3.next();
                if(it3Entry.mChannelDetails.mObjectClusterName.equals(it2Entry.mChannelDetails.mObjectClusterName)){
                    it3.remove(); // this line is causing a concurrentModificationException
                    break innerloop;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to your question. The stack trace also contains the exact line number where the problem occurs, so it may help you to highlight it without guessing.

Comment: Start by using appropriate generics to make your code easier to read.

Comment: @RealSkeptic stack trace added in the edit.. it confirms the line throwing the exception is it3.remove()

Answer (score 1):

`plotDeviceDetails.mListOfPlotChannelDetails` and `firstMap.get(mapKey).mListOfPlotChannelDetails` reference the *same* list.

Whether `plotDeviceDetails` and `firstMap.get(mapKey)` also reference the same object is unknown without more information, but they share the channel list.

Comment: They are the same list in name only..plotDeviceDetails.mListOfPlotChannelDetails is the list entry for secondmap where as firstMap.get(mapKey).mListOfPlotChannelDetails is the list entry for the firstmap. They don't reference the same object,,

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace is showing that `mListOfPlotChannelDetails` is an `ArrayList`, and since the stack trace also shows that the error is coming from `it3.remove()`, and there is nothing in the code that can cause that, then you are truly facing a concurrent modification, i.e. another thread has updated the `ArrayList` being iterated by `it3`.

Remember, `ArrayList` does *not* support concurrent multi-thread access.